# Use two/multiple selected directories from custom page in Files section

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

I need create custom page of two destination.

I've done:

```pascal
#define MyAppName "TESTPROG"
[Setup]

AppName={#MyAppName}
DefaultDirName=C:\test\{#MyAppName}
DefaultGroupName={#MyAppName}

[Code]
var
  Page: TInputDirWizardPage;
  DataDir: String;

procedure InitializeWizard;
begin
  Page := CreateInputDirPage(wpWelcome,
    'Select Personal Data Location', 'Where should personal data files be stored?',
    'Personal data files will be stored in the following folder.'#13#10#13#10 +
    'To continue, click Next. ' +
      'If you would like to select a different folder, click Browse.',
    False, 'New Folder');

  Page.Add('Local APP');
  Page.Add('Local Storage');

  Page.Values[0] := ('C:\My Program');
  Page.Values[1] := ('D:\My Program');

  DataDir := Page.Values[0]; 
end;
```

I need to know how and where I set DefaultDirName with `Page.Values[0]` and `Page.Values[1]`

I need it because some part of my files will be in a folder and others in other folder.

For example:

```
[Files]
Source: C:\TEST\DLL1.bat; DestDir: Page.Values[0]\sys1;
Source: C:\TEST\DLL2.bat; DestDir: Page.Values[1]\sys2;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a [scripted constant](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptconstants):

```pascal
[Files]
Source: C:\TEST\DLL1.bat; DestDir: "{code:GetDir|0}\sys1"
Source: C:\TEST\DLL2.bat; DestDir: "{code:GetDir|1}\sys2"

[Code]

var
  Page: TInputDirWizardPage;

function GetDir(Param: string): string;
begin
  Result := Page.Values[StrToInt(Param)];
end;

procedure InitializeWizard;
begin
  Page := CreateInputDirPage(...);
  ...
end;
```

---

If you want to use one of the (the first) paths from the `TInputDirWizardPage` instead of the path from *"Select Destination Location"* page, you have three options.

1. Disable the *"Select Destination Location"* page using [`DisableDirPage` directive](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_disabledirpage):

   ```
   DisableDirPage=yes
   ```

   Copy the path from the `TInputDirWizardPage` to the hidden *"Select 
   Destination Location"* page, when the user presses *Next* button:

   ```pascal
   var
     Page: TInputDirWizardPage;

   function InputDirPageNextButtonClick(Sender: TWizardPage): Boolean;
   begin
     { Use the first path as the "destination path" }
     WizardForm.DirEdit.Text := Page.Values[0];
     Result := True;
   end;

   procedure InitializeWizard();
   begin
     Page := CreateInputDirPage(...);
     ...
     Page.OnNextButtonClick := @InputDirPageNextButtonClick;
   end;
   ```

   To complement that you may also consider copying the initial `WizardForm.DirEdit` to your custom box. This way you make sure that 1) on re-install/upgrade, the previously selected value is reused; 2) [`/DIR` command-line switch](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setupcmdline&anchor=DIR) works. For that see [How to make Inno Setup /DIR command line switch work with custom path page](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46392695/850848).
2. Replace all uses of the [`{app}` constant](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=consts&anchor=app) with `{code:GetDir|0}`.

   Make Inno Setup not create the `{app}` path using [`CreateAppDir` directive](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_createappdir):

   ```
   CreateAppDir=no
   ```

   (this implies `DisableDirPage=yes`).

   And have the uninstall files be stored in the first path using [`UninstallFilesDir` directive](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_uninstallfilesdir):

   ```
   UninstallFilesDir={code:GetDir|0}
   ```

   Contrary to 1), with this approach the previous installation path won't get reused for the later upgrade/re-install. To implement that see [Inno Setup Prompt user for a folder and store the value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33735226/850848).
3. Do not use the `CreateInputDirPage`, but rather add a second path input box on the *"Select Destination Location"* page (`SelectDirPage`).