# Inno Setup custom page with multiple destination folders that behave like the normal folder select page

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

I've the following code (taken from [Use two/multiple selected directories from custom page in Files section](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36317959/850848)):

```pascal
[Code]
var
  DirPage: TInputDirWizardPage;

function GetDir(Param: String): String;
begin
  Result := DirPage.Values[StrToInt(Param)];
end;

procedure InitializeWizard;
var
  S1, S2: String; 
begin
  S1 := SetupMessage(msgSelectDirDesc);
  StringChangeEx(S1, '[name]', 'ProgramName', false);
  S2 := SetupMessage(msgSelectDirLabel3);
  StringChangeEx(S2, '[name]', 'ProgramName', false);

  { create a directory input page }
  DirPage := CreateInputDirPage(
    wpSelectDir, SetupMessage(msgWizardSelectDir), S1, S2, False, '');
  { add directory input page items }
  DirPage.Add('Path to Apache:');
  DirPage.Add('Path to PHP:');
  DirPage.Add('Path to Server Files:');
  { assign default directories for the items from the previously stored data; if }
  { there are no data stored from the previous installation, use default folders }
  { of your choice }
  DirPage.Values[0] := GetPreviousData('Directory1', 'C:\Apache');
  DirPage.Values[1] := GetPreviousData('Directory2', 'C:\PHP');
  DirPage.Values[2] := GetPreviousData('Directory3', 'C:\Apache\htdocs\Server Files');
end;

procedure RegisterPreviousData(PreviousDataKey: Integer);
begin
  { store chosen directories for the next run of the setup }
  SetPreviousData(PreviousDataKey, 'Directory1', DirPage.Values[0]);
  SetPreviousData(PreviousDataKey, 'Directory2', DirPage.Values[1]);
  SetPreviousData(PreviousDataKey, 'Directory3', DirPage.Values[2]);
end;
```

I'd like to make this behave like the traditional folder select page, so when selecting a folder, Inno Setup should keep the default folder name unless manually overwritten by the user. I.e.: if I select the folder `"C:\Program Files\"` it should keep the original folder like `"C:\Program Files\PHP"` or `"C:\Program Files\Apache"`. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the default behavior of *Browse* button on *"Select Destination Location"*  (triggered by [`AppendDefaultDirName` directive](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_appenddefaultdirname)), for *Browse* buttons on your custom page, set these parameters of [`CreateInputDirPage`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_createinputdirpage):

- `AAppendDir` to `True`
- `ANewFolderName` to the "default folder name"

The problem is, that this affects all input boxes/buttons. While you want to affect only the first input box/button (or you want a different `ANewFolderName` for each box/button).

---

To modify a behavior of some box only, you have to reimplement their functionality from the scratch. Though the browse dialog functionality is not exposed. There's only [`BrowseForFolder` function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_browseforfolder), which is slightly different.

```pascal
var
  DirPage: TInputDirWizardPage;

procedure NormalBrowseClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  Directory: string;
begin
  Directory := DirPage.Values[TButton(Sender).Tag];
  if BrowseForFolder(SetupMessage(msgWizardSelectDir), Directory, False) then
  begin
    DirPage.Values[TButton(Sender).Tag] := Directory;
  end;
end;

procedure InitializeWizard();
begin
  DirPage := CreateInputDirPage(
    wpSelectDir, SetupMessage(msgWizardSelectDir), '', '', True, 'Apache');
  { add directory input page items }
  DirPage.Add('Path to Apache:');
  DirPage.Add('Path to PHP:');
  DirPage.Add('Path to Server Files:');

  DirPage.Buttons[1].Tag := 1;
  DirPage.Buttons[1].OnClick := @NormalBrowseClick;
  DirPage.Buttons[2].Tag := 2;
  DirPage.Buttons[2].OnClick := @NormalBrowseClick;
  { assign default directories for the items from the previously stored data; if }
  { there are no data stored from the previous installation, use default folders }
  { of your choice }
  DirPage.Values[0] := GetPreviousData('Directory1', 'C:\Apache');
  DirPage.Values[1] := GetPreviousData('Directory2', 'C:\PHP');
  DirPage.Values[2] := GetPreviousData('Directory3', 'C:\Apache\htdocs\Server Files');
end;
```

---

To get the exact behaviour with the same "browse" dialog, you can hack it be invoking a functionality of the hidden *"Select Destination Location"* page or of another hidden `TInputDirWizardPage` with different settings of `AAppendDir`:

```pascal
var
  DirPage: TInputDirWizardPage;
  HiddenPage: TInputDirWizardPage;

procedure AppendDirBrowseClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  HiddenPage.Values[0] := DirPage.Values[0];
  HiddenPage.Buttons[0].OnClick(HiddenPage.Buttons[0]);
  DirPage.Values[0] := HiddenPage.Values[0];
end;

function SkipPage(Sender: TWizardPage): Boolean;
begin
  Result := True;
end;

procedure InitializeWizard();
begin
  DirPage := CreateInputDirPage(
    wpSelectDir, SetupMessage(msgWizardSelectDir), '', '', False, '');

  DirPage.Add('Path to Apache:');
  DirPage.Add('Path to PHP:');
  DirPage.Add('Path to Server Files:');

  { assign default directories for the items from the previously stored data; if }
  { there are no data stored from the previous installation, use default folders }
  { of your choice }
  DirPage.Values[0] := GetPreviousData('Directory1', 'C:\Apache');
  DirPage.Values[1] := GetPreviousData('Directory2', 'C:\PHP');
  DirPage.Values[2] := GetPreviousData('Directory3', 'C:\Apache\htdocs\Server Files');

  DirPage.Buttons[0].OnClick := @AppendDirBrowseClick;

  HiddenPage := CreateInputDirPage(
    wpSelectDir, SetupMessage(msgWizardSelectDir), '', '', True, 'Apache');
  HiddenPage.Add('');
  HiddenPage.OnShouldSkipPage := @SkipPage;
end;
```

The code needs Unicode version of Inno Setup. Calling `HiddenPage.Buttons[0].OnClick` strangely does not work in Ansi version.

Comment: So am I wrong in assuming that *"you want to affect only the first input box/button"*? Then use the trivial solution suggested in the first section.

Comment: I'd like to affect each button with it's specific directory. Button1 should add "Apache", Button2 "PHP", Button3 "Server Files" to the path that is browsed. So I can't use the first code sample (or I couldn't figure out how to customize it).

Comment: OK, I see. So you can use the code from the third section. Just that you need to create two hidden pages, each with `AAppendDir = True` and different settings of `ANewFolderName`.

Comment: This works, I've posted an answer with the final code.

Answer (score 2):

For future reference, here is the full working code based on Martin's answer. Make sure to add "DisableDirPage=yes" to the [Setup] section.

*Note: Due to a bug, the code below works only in the unicode version of InnoSetup.*

```
[Code]
var
  DirPage: TInputDirWizardPage;
  HiddenPage: TInputDirWizardPage;
  HiddenPage2: TInputDirWizardPage;
  HiddenPage3: TInputDirWizardPage;

procedure AppendDirBrowseClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  HiddenPage.Values[0] := DirPage.Values[0];
  HiddenPage.Buttons[0].OnClick(HiddenPage.Buttons[0]);
  DirPage.Values[0] := HiddenPage.Values[0];
end;

procedure AppendDirBrowseClick2(Sender: TObject);
begin
  HiddenPage2.Values[0] := DirPage.Values[1];
  HiddenPage2.Buttons[0].OnClick(HiddenPage2.Buttons[0]);
  DirPage.Values[1] := HiddenPage2.Values[0];
end;

procedure AppendDirBrowseClick3(Sender: TObject);
begin
  HiddenPage3.Values[0] := DirPage.Values[2];
  HiddenPage3.Buttons[0].OnClick(HiddenPage3.Buttons[0]);
  DirPage.Values[2] := HiddenPage3.Values[0];
end;

function SkipPage(Sender: TWizardPage): Boolean;
begin
  Result := True;
end;

procedure InitializeWizard();
begin
  DirPage := CreateInputDirPage(
    wpSelectDir, SetupMessage(msgWizardSelectDir), '', '', False, '');

  DirPage.Add('Path to Apache:');
  DirPage.Add('Path to PHP:');
  DirPage.Add('Path to Server Files:');

  { assign default directories for the items from the previously stored data; if }
  { there are no data stored from the previous installation, use default folders }
  { of your choice }
  DirPage.Values[0] := GetPreviousData('Directory1', 'C:\Apache');
  DirPage.Values[1] := GetPreviousData('Directory2', 'C:\PHP');
  DirPage.Values[2] := GetPreviousData('Directory3', 'C:\Apache\htdocs\Server Files');

  DirPage.Buttons[0].OnClick := @AppendDirBrowseClick;
  DirPage.Buttons[1].OnClick := @AppendDirBrowseClick2;
  DirPage.Buttons[2].OnClick := @AppendDirBrowseClick3;

  HiddenPage := CreateInputDirPage(
    wpSelectDir, SetupMessage(msgWizardSelectDir), '', '', True, 'Apache');
  HiddenPage.Add('');
  HiddenPage.OnShouldSkipPage := @SkipPage;

  HiddenPage2 := CreateInputDirPage(
    wpSelectDir, SetupMessage(msgWizardSelectDir), '', '', True, 'PHP');
  HiddenPage2.Add('');
  HiddenPage2.OnShouldSkipPage := @SkipPage;

  HiddenPage3 := CreateInputDirPage(
    wpSelectDir, SetupMessage(msgWizardSelectDir), '', '', True, 'Server Files');
  HiddenPage3.Add('');
  HiddenPage3.OnShouldSkipPage := @SkipPage;
end;
```