# How to keep the original folder name (AppendDefaultDirName equivalent) on a custom page created with CreateInputDirPage

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

I want to keep the original folder name as it is. So when selecting the location on custom directory page, Inno Setup should keep the default folder name unless manually overwritten by the user. That is, if the default location is `c:\MS`, if the user selects `d:\` drive, then it must be `d:\MS`.

Have tried setting `AppendDefaultDirName` to `yes`. But still I am not getting the expected result.

```pascal
[Setup]
DefaultDirName={tmp}\MyProg
AppendDefaultDirName=yes

[Code]

procedure InitializeWizard();
begin
  DirPage := CreateInputDirPage(
    wpSelectDir, 'Directory Selection', 'Choose where to install.', false, '');
  DirPage.Add('Select Custom Location ');
  DirPage.Values[0] := GetPreviousData('Directory1', 'C:\MS');
end;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set [`CreateInputDirPage`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_createinputdirpage) arguments like this:

- `AAppendDir` to `True`;
- `ANewFolderName` to `'MS'`:

```pascal
CreateInputDirPage(
  wpSelectDir, 'Directory Selection', 'Choose where to install.', '', True, 'MS');
```

---

*(`AppendDefaultDirName` has no effect on `CreateInputDirPage`)*

---

For a similar, but more complex question, see:
[Inno Setup custom page with multiple destination folders that behave like the normal folder select page](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53784498/850848)