# Save credentials to Windows Credentials Manager using Inno Setup

Tags: windows, installation, inno-setup

We want to store customer specific credentials for our application in the Windows Credential Manager using Inno Setup.

We are building an installer that installs a part of our software in customer environments. We want the installer asking for those a client id and a client secret. And then we want to store this credentials in the Windows Credential Manager during the installation process. How can we achieve this?

I have seen those potentially interesting questions but I lack the understanding of how to use this in Inno Setup:

- [How to access the stored credentials (PasswordVault?) on Win7 and Win8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14813370/how-to-access-the-stored-credentials-passwordvault-on-win7-and-win8)
- [Access Windows Credentials in Credential Manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29214288/access-windows-credentials-in-credential-manager)

Windows service using those credentials will be running using the same account that runs the installer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can simply run [`cmdkey`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/cmdkey) from Inno Setup, providing it credentials specified by the user (e.g. on a custom page):

```
[Run]
Filename: {sys}\cmdkey.exe; \
    Parameters: "/add:target /user:""{code:GetCred|0}"" /pass:""{code:GetCred|1}"""
```

```pascal
[Code]
var
  Page: TInputDirWizardPage;

function GetCred(Param: string): string;
begin
  Result := Page.Values[StrToInt(Param)];
end;
```

You of course need to create the `Page` first using [`CreateInputQueryPage`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_createinputquerypage).

Similar questions:

- [Use two/multiple selected directories from custom page in Files section](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36317959/850848)
- [Inno Setup Prompt user for a folder and store the value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33735226/850848)